# Textbox and Combo box not showing background color from theme

Tags: codenameone

I have a project in the play store created with version 3.2 at end of October.  Today I rebuilt the project to add new features.  When I deployed it to Android I noticed the following 4 issues.
1. The push notification icon is a solid white square.  It was my icon in the past.
2. The initial screen form is incorrect as it goes into the android soft buttons at the bottom of the page.
3. The theme for my combo box is not showing. Just see thru to background.
4. The text field background is also just using the background instead of the white.

I tried building in latest, 3.2 and 3.1 with no differences.  I reverted all code to the release in October with no help.

I submitted the IOS build and everything is fine.
The simulator shows everything is fine.
I tried many times to figure out why this is happening and have not been able to.

I need 10 reputation points to post more than 2 links so, I'm only showing  2 screen shots. Let me know if you want the others.

Please see the following:

[This image shows the edit and dropdown issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtU6v.png)
[This is the current play store version of the edit and dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEPjg.png)

Any ideas on how can I fix these issues?  For the text field I use my own style (it does get the boarder but not the background).  The notification icon, I don't see how anything I can do would affect this.

Thank you
Sam

-- Edited --
I did manage to get these working again.

I was setting the background color using the theme background tab and setting a gradient with upper and lower the same color.  I changed this to NONE, then in the color tab set the background color.

Notification needed a new icon as specified by Chen.  In my case the app icon is basically a square and doesn't transfer well to a notification icon.

The last was the nexus 9 initial screen painting into the bottom navigation control.  This is still happening and is easily reproduced by making a new hello world codename one app with no changes.

Comment: From android 5+ only white icons with transparency can be shown on the bar. We try to remove black color from the app icon to produce such icon, but it obviously will fail for some icons. just place a 24x24 icon with the name "ic_stat_notify.png" in your src/ folder and the build server will pick it up.

Comment: Thank you, I added an ic_stat_notify with a different format and the icon looks better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the background color using the theme background tab and setting a gradient with upper and lower the same color didn't work.

Change this to NONE, then in the color tab set the background color.

Comment: You should never use the gradients and should try using images which are MUCH faster...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `android.asyncPaint=false` build hint?

I understand some issues occurred with it although I doubt you would see them if you are using the versioned build.

Comment: Hi Shai,  I didn't have that set so I tried it and it did fix the 3 issues, unfortunately cause all kinds of overwrite.
Is it possible that even though Im selecting 3.2 I am getting the current version?  I keep generated source code when I deploy and when I compare the notification section it is different than the prior 3.2 (has code to handle messageType = 4 that was not there before.)  How can I determine if 3.2 is really used for the build.  The build also switched from ant to gradle.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `android.asyncPaint=false` as we are focusing the bulk of our effort on getting the main pipeline to perform well. To make sure 3.2 is used just include the sources and look at something that changed between 3.3 and 3.2